# Working with SASS in a Mono WebForms Project

Tags: asp.net, webforms, mono, sass

I am in the process of creating a website using Mono.  It will be a standard webforms app (not MVC) but I'd like to use SASS for the CSS (specifically scss). However, I can't seem to get SASS to work with a mono webforms application.  I tried using SassAndCoffee from NuGet and followed the standard setup instructions which said I should just reference my scss files as css files (e.g. application.scss would be referenced as application.css in a link attribute in the head. see http://blog.paulbetts.org/index.php/category/programming/mono-net/).  That didn't work (or at least I'm assuming it didn't since my page rendered with no CSS and this scss has been tested on a rails platform so I know it works).

Next I tried using SquishIt which has an NSass wrapper.  I followed the instructions here: http://www.cassandraking.net/wordpressapp/integrating-sass-into-net-using-nuget-and-squishit-sass/.  This throw a 500 error because asp.net was unable to find NSass.Wrapper.proxy.dll. A quick google search led me to discover that because I was targeting "Any CPU", it couldn't choose between "NSass.Wrapper.x86" and NSass.Wrapper.x64".  Sadly, however, MonoDevelop doesn't seem to want to give me the option to target x86 or x64 (the only option I have is to target "Any CPU").

I've kind of run out of options. Since I'm not using MVC, am I able to using SASS with a standard WebForms project using the Mono platform? Has anyone done this and can provide me some pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else runs into this, I never really found a viable solution in terms of a plugin.  Honestly, Xamarin studio doesn't even seem to have a built in SASS editor as it isn't able to colour code anything in a SASS file.  I ended up just using the sass command in terminal to convert a sass file to css. At a terminal prompt in the folder where your sass is kept type:

```
$ sass mysassfilename.sass:somecssfilename.css
```

To edit the sass file, I downloaded Microsoft's Visual Studio Code which has a version for the mac.  It works rather well.

Comment: I mostly work on a Mac but am primarily a .NET developer and have found Xamarin Studio falls short in a few areas so thanks for this :-)